# Can you re-use code in SSIS? Can you programmatically change source/target?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have about 10 different csv files that I need to parse and transform and load into sql server.

I don't want to create 10 different ssis packages for this, would it be possible to create a single SSIS package that I could create 10 different instances of, and simply alter a config file so that it pulls from the correct source csf file and saves to the correct table?

Is it also possible to create re-usable parts of code that would do things like email a report of what was loaded, what had errors and what the erros were etc.  There are other parts that I am sure I could re-use between the 10 different files that need to be parsed.

Also, is modifying and deploying a ssis package painful?

Comment: Are the csv the same format with different names? Do they have the same columns but perhaps in a different order? If yes to either of those, then yes, you can dynamically set the connection string to the flat file via an Expression at runtime and SSIS can go on its merry way. For re-use, I'd look at a parent-child paradigm. Parent picks the right package to parse the data and when the child is done, it reports back to the parent a consistent set of data the parent then parses and does its thing. I'll provide links once I know more about your data.

Answer (score 0):

This question is same as the below one. I got a solution for that and it really helped me. Hope it will help you.

[Best Way to ETL Multiple Different Excel Sheets Into SQL Server 2008 Using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241472/best-way-to-etl-multiple-different-excel-sheets-into-sql-server-2008-using-ssis/10277948#10277948)